# Keyclock access token not expired even though session is closed

Tags: session, single-sign-on, keycloak, access-token

I am new to keyclock currently using version 21.0.2, Integrating keyclock with spring application facing issue with access token not expiring even though session is closed (logged out).

Comment: Can you check whether the access token lifespan and session timeouts at auth/admin/<realm>/console/#/prod/realm-settings/sessions and auth/admin/<realm>/console/#/prod/realm-settings/tokens

Comment: sirish, i checked, access token works till the accessTokenLifespan expired + 2 mins , but it should expiry its when session is closed. if no session, then the access should not be done,my issue is I am accessing api  with the access token of expired session

Comment: When you logout in your spring application, do you see any sessions for the corresponding user in keycloak? If session still persists, it may be an issue with logout in your application. I tried this using admin cli, after manually deleting the session access token no longer works.